# List of languages supported in Google Cloud Vision OCR detection?

Tags: android, ocr, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Working on some modules using Google Cloud Vision API for text detection and was wondering if anyone has list of languages/text it can detect.
Personal experience with Italian, French, English, Chinese, Spanish works. What about the ones like Hindi, Urdu etc?

Thanks and appreciate your help!
Suman

Answer (score 2):

The list of supported languages for the Vision API OCR is [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/translate-reference#supported_languages) (this list is linked from the Vision API [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#imagecontext)).

Comment: Hey Sara, thanks for the response. I have tried some text in different languages and the ones that I have seen passing with my app which uses Cloud Vision - [Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.suman.news_hound&hl=en) are [Chinese, English, Finnish, French, German, Japanese, Korean, Portugese & Spanish].

Comment: The ones I certainly saw failing are Telugu, Hindi and Urdu, where it didn't identify the text ideally. I even tried the OCR trial thing where we upload text images through browser and seems Hindi failed. 
I can certainly try once more and see if it works.

Comment: Tried again some text in hindi and seem to be failing. Please let me know if missing anything.

Comment: Any updates on this Sara?

Comment: Why is this answer unacceptable? It answers the question completely.

Comment: Hi RMtheis, I have tried myself and out of the whole list the language noted are that I saw working, Hindi and Urdu failed. so either the list is not accurate or Google hasn't rolled out all of the features yet. Tried reaching sales too and they are yet to get back to me :(